# boot fails after setting grub background

Tags: grub

On Linux Mint, everything was working fine, but then I set GRUB_BACKGROUND=/my/path.jpg in /etc/default/grub.cfg

Then I ran `sudo update-grub` and restarted

The background did appear, but when I choose my normal boot it now just displays that background with no other text and hangs

If I try booting into recovery mode it just hangs on `Loading initial ramdisk`

How could this have happened? Did I inadvertently change something other than just the background when I ran update-grub?

I checked for any `quiet` flags in the boot options but can't see any, so I don't know what to do from here

Comment: What version of Mint are you using, and are you certain it was `/etc/default/grub.cfg` you changed? I've got Mint 20.2, and it has no file `/etc/default/grub.cfg`. It has files `/etc/default/grub` and `/boot/grub/grub.cfg`.

Comment: @DavidYockey I am also on 20.2 - and ye it was that file but I had to create it. I'm wondering if its a red herring and I'm thinking `update-grub` probably did something else at the same time

Comment: I don't know why your action had any effect, unless `/etc/default/grub.cfg` is a legacy file still processed by `update-grub`, but creating that file may not have been the way to go. My understanding, as implied by this bit about [how GRUB 2 works](https://www.dedoimedo.com/computers/grub-2.html#mozTocId514088), is that `/etc/default/grub` (with no `.cfg` extension) should be edited and then `update-grub` should be run to update the `grub.cfg` file.